# jquery contains acting different in jquery v3 and v2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try to target a table row based on its content:

```
$(function() {
$('tr td:contains("SomeString")').css('background-color', 'black'); 
});
```

when I use jquery v3 it works perfectly, but when I switch to v2 it does not work.

I have to use v2 due to bootstrap requirements. 
Also, it puzzles me: it is a basic function - where is my mistake?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Actually, this code works as expected for me with jquery version 2.2.4 and version 3.0.0

Comment: I think, I know what is wrong. I use d3js to draw a table. When I constructed the table  in ordinary way everything was fine. 

What should be the order of scripts?
Right now: 
jquery and bootstrap scripts in the <head>
d3 function drawing table before </body> tag followed by the jquery contains() function.

Comment: So, to reiterate my question:

What is the proper order of functions when I populate table using d3js and then want to target rows based on its content?

I tried many things and still it does not work, jquery v2 can't see table populated by d3js.

Comment: You want the jQuery script to run after the d3 populates the table, which you have. However, is your d3js doing an asynchronous call to fetch the data to populate the table? If so, the jQuery part is probably still running before the table is populated. Can you confirm?

Comment: How can I check whether d3 calls data asynchronously?

Comment: What web browser are you using?

Comment: chrome and safari

PS. I tried to use $(window).load(function()
No luck

Comment: In Chrome, open your developer tools, choose the Network tab, and filter on XHR:  http://i.imgur.com/HjTi44o.png

Then refresh your page.  In that developer window, you will see a list of asynchronous requests.  What does that look like?

Comment: Can you show us what your d3js code looks like?

Comment: Sure:
    d3.text("csv/tabela.csv", function(data) {
                var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("tbody")
                    

                    .selectAll("tr")
                        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                        .append("tr")
                .attr("id", function(d) { return d[0]; })

                    .selectAll("td")
                        .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) { return d; })
          });

Comment: XHR: http://imgur.com/Vl9x0fu
JS: http://imgur.com/Q6VPW2k

tabela.js is the script drawing table
and 
zaznacz.js is the jquery script targeting the table rows

Comment: d3 code in pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/KsK4WbpB

Comment: Yep!  As I mentioned, your d3 is fetching data asynchronously and then populating the table after that XHR request completes.  In other words, your code is doing:

1 - fire the XHR request to get the table data
2 - style the table based on SomeString
3 - use the data fetched the the XHR request to populate the table in the webpage

The quick solution is to put your jQuery code inside your d3.text call, so your code looks like:  http://pastebin.com/raw/DnE8c2ZY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the final answer will look something like this:  http://pastebin.com/Xf55FcvL

Comment: Awesome, I am really grateful. Works great. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Happy to help!  Cheers!